# Problems with making a desktop shortcut to a shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have looked at many different posts about doing this, but none of the solutions have worked. I have already made both the shell script and the shortcut  executable. Any other ideas?

Here is the code for my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Auth Username: vpnbook \n\n"
printf "Auth Password: ne6Arupe \n\n"
printf "The password is subject to change. If you encounter an authentication error, visit www.vpnbok.com
printf "To exit the VPN, press control C\n\n"

sudo openvpn vpnbook-de233-tcp443.ovpn
```

And here is the shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=True
Name=VPN
Exec=/home/(username)/.vpn/vpn.sh
```

Whenever I double click the shortcut, I get "There was an error launching the application."
Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you try running you script in a terminal before attempting to launch it from the desktop? there is a missing closing quote in the line that begins `printf "The password is subject to ... `

Comment: Yes. The script does run fine, just not when I click on the desktop shortcut.

Comment: can you try `Terminal=true`, not sure if case matters so ck.

Comment: It doesn't seem like case matters, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window:

`chmod +x /home/(username)/.vpn/vpn.sh` to allow execution.

If you want only the owner to have this right, you may use `u+x` instead of `x`.

Also, remove the space after #!.  The correct syntax is `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I tried it and I still got the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added the space removal in my answer.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that too and still got the same error. I think that it may be a problem with the shortcut, because the script runs fine.

Comment: The space between `#!` and `/bin/bash` is not significant AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Exec line to:

```
Exec=bash /home/(username)/.vpn/vpn.sh
```

Comment: I still seem to get the same error when I do that.